# How to insert 0 in a string

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

this is my array :

```
eth1
eth12
eth5
eth11
```

When my string contains a number between 1 and 9 i want to add a 0 before, to obtain an array like this :

```
eth01
eth12
eth05
eth11
```

How can i achieve this? i don't know how to modify a string like this :/

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Like this:

```
$if = 'eth1', 'eth12', 'eth5', 'eth11'
$if -replace '(\D+)(\d)$', '${1}0$2'
```

Answer (score 4):

Another option:

```
$if -replace '(?<=\D)(\d)$', '0$1'
```

Answer (score 1):

a more tortuous way than Ansgar's  :)

```
$a=@("eth1","eth12","eth5")

$a|%{
    $slice=$_.split("h");
    if([int]$slice[1] -le 9){
        $slice[1]="0"+$slice[1]
    }
join-string -strings $slice -separator("h")
}
```